# card flight phonegap plugin android

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, cardreader

I'm using Card Flight Phone gap plugin in my application and on loading the page where i've initialized the plugin the application terminates abruplty with a message "Unfortunalely,  stopped working ". The error log captured in eclipse is as follows.

```
`10-05 09:45:00.071 11377 11413  ResourceType No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000

10-05 09:45:00.071 11377 11413  dalvikvm threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=ox416eedao)

10-05 09:48:00.081 11377 11413 AndroidRuntime FAIAL EXCEPTION: JavaBridge

10-05 09:48:00.081 11377 11413 AndroidRuntime Process: com.corra.bcApp, PID: 11377

10-05 09:48:00.081 11377 11413 AndroidRuntime android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #oxo

10-05 09:48:00.081 11377 11413 AndroidRuntime at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1134)

10-05 09:48:00.081 11377 11413 AndroidRuntime at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:1228)

10-05 09:48:00.081 11377 11413 AndroidRuntime at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:363)

10-05 09:48:00.081 11377 11413 AndroidRuntime at com.getcardflight.models.M.C(Unknown Source)

10-05 09:48:00.081 11377 11413 AndroidRuntime at com.getcardflight.models.M.a(Unknown Source)

10-05 09:48:00.081 11377 11413 AndroidRuntime at com.a.b.aK.run(SourceFile:1491)

10-05 09:48:00.081 11377 11413 AndroidRuntime at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)

10-05 09:48:00.081 11377 11413 AndroidRuntime at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

10-05 09:48:00.081 11377 11413 AndroidRuntime at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)

10-05 09:48:00.081 11377 11413 AndroidRuntime at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)`
```

I'm not able to identify the cause of the crash. Can some one help me with is.?? If any more information is required please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the plugin by pgdaniel https://github.com/pgdaniel/cordova_cardflight it looks like it only works with iOS right now.

http://plugreg.com/plugin/pgdaniel/cordova_cardflight shows the compatibility, also inspecting the repo on github only shows a `src/ios` folder.

Have you found a solution to this?  I also want to use cardflight on android.